# How to change the terminal working directory with cli script?

Tags: php

I would like to change the directory in Linux terminal from cli script, **not the PHP current working directory** -- hopefully with shell_exec().

Ex: from `user@host:~$` to `user@host:/the/other/directory$`

`system()` and `exec()` are not allowed.

This isn't working in my case:

```
$dir = '/the/other/directory';
shell_exec('cd '.$dir);
```

nor these

```
shell_exec('cd '.escapeshellarg($dir));
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('cd '.$dir));
pclose(popen('cd '.$dir));
```

But `shell_exec('ls '.$dir)` gives me the list in that directory. Any trickery?

Comment: Do you have privileges to access that folder?

Comment: How can you say it is not working?

Comment: @hakre The cwd is not changing to desired location

Comment: How can you say that? I don't see any pwd call **in the same shell_exec** that is showing that you actually verify the directory change in the shell.

Comment: The getpwd() or any verification in the script is irrelevant. I would like to change the terminal working directory: from user@host:~$ to user@host:/the/other/directory$ using cli script.

Comment: I think PHP handles them as they are and the previous command doesn't effect the following. Use chdir. http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Comment: @MikkoP Tried that too, chdir($dir) before calling shell_exec() and still no joy :\

Comment: Have you tried to echo the return value of the command? Maybe it says no such folder?

Comment: Of course, the result is NULL. Also checked the access.log and error.log; nothing interesting there too.

Comment: Each shell has it's own working direcktory. Each time you open a new shell (you call `shell_exec`) it starts from scratch. Is that so hard to understand?

Comment: Does shell_exec("cd path; ls"); display the right content?

@hakre Shouldn't chdir change the working directory?

Comment: @MikkoP: Maybe, but I think this dependes on the SAPI used.

Comment: @hakre Thank you for clarifying that, your answer is appreciated. That's why I asked the question "How to change the terminal working directory with cli script?".

Comment: I normally have no problem to change the working directory with a CLI script, I use chdir for it. works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

When you're executing several commands like you are doing:

```
shell_exec('cd '.escapeshellarg($dir));
shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('cd '.$dir));
```

It won't work. The first command has nothing to do with the second one, so you can't use the results of the 1st command to execute the 2nd command.

If you want to execute a chain of commands, use the pipe symbol `|` like:

```
echo shell_exec("ls /etc/apache2 | grep fileName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Local changes made by shell_exec only apply to that php process and therefore ls would fetch from that other directory. But when you exit the php, you are back to bash who never really cares what process does.

I doubt you can change bash's current directory from outside.
If you need to run bash in other directory, you could try this inside your php:

```
system('gnome-terminal --working-directtory=/home/doom');
```

this will start another terminal in new dir but script will wait till you quit this shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to change the parent shell's directory by calling a php cli script, then you can't do that. What you could do is at best:

```
shell> eval `your/cli/script`
```

and in your script do something like

```
<?php
...
    echo "cd $dir"

?>
```